# Where I can find an example MVC 4 / ASP 4.5 / Websockets

Tags: websocket, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have installed Visual Studio 2012 RC.
I would like to find any example of MVC and websockets but I'don't find one.

I'm interested in the server part.

I have found some infromation here:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/idof/archive/2012/03/06/what-s-new-in-wcf-4-5-websocket-support-part-2-of-2.aspx

And I have found this sample:

https://github.com/paulbatum/WebSocket-Samples

I will try to do something with this :)

Comment: Are you interested in the client part of the WebSockets or you want to write a WebSockets server in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: In the server part in ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this source to learn about how to implement the server part:

http://marcinbudny.blogspot.de/2011/10/websockets-in-net-45-simple-game.html

I think it was very usefull.